# INSERT INTO syntax error in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert-into

I have this code... when the aspx.vb tries to insert I receive the error of syntax, I check the DB (access file) and I see everything ok.

Maybe I mixing the DB fields name in the insert statement.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlString, FName, LName, NT, ACD, Account, Clocka, Supervisor, Shift, Shiftnew, Days, Clock, Emp, Commm, HR, doff As String
    Dim MailContent As String = String.Concat("      Requestor     ", Name.Text, "   Agent ID    ", Last.Text, "    AGENT NT      ", NTE.Text, "      Account       ", DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "    Supervisor      ", DropDownList2.SelectedValue, "    Current Shift     ", DropDownList6.SelectedValue, "      Current Shift Start Time      ", DropDownList7.SelectedValue, "   New Shift       ", DropDownList4.SelectedValue, "     New Shift Start Time      ", DropDownList3.SelectedValue, "      Addendum sent to HR?      ", RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue, "     Days off    ", TextBox2.Text, "    Comments        ", TextBox1.Text)

    FName = Name.Text
    LName = Last.Text
    NT = NTE.Text
    ACD = ACDE.Text
    Account = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Supervisor = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
    Shift = DropDownList4.SelectedValue
    Clocka = DropDownList7.SelectedValue
    Emp = DropDownList5.SelectedValue
    Shiftnew = DropDownList6.SelectedValue
    Clock = DropDownList3.SelectedValue
    doff = TextBox2.Text
    HR = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue
    Days = Calendar1.SelectedDate
    Commm = TextBox1.Text

    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Information submitted successfully!!!');</script>")

    myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WFM\Database4.accdb")

    myConn.Open()
    ' sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Tipo, Justification, Clock, Cuando) VALUES ( " + FName + "," + LName + "," + Account + "," + Supervisor + "," + Type + "," + Justification + "," + Clock + "," + Days + ")"

    sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (Requestor, Employee ID, NT, ACD, Account, Supervisor, Current Shift, Current Shift Start Time, Employee type, New Shift, New Shift Start Time, Days Off, HR, Shift Start, Comments) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @NT, @ACD, @Account, @Supervisor, @Shift, @Clocka, @Emp, @Shiftnew, @Clock, @doff, @HR, @Days, @Commm)"
    'sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (FName, LName, NT, ACD, Account, Supervisor, Shift, Clocka, Emp, Shiftnew, Clock, doff, HR, Days, Commm) VALUES (@Requestor, @Employee ID, @NT, @ACD, @Account, @Supervisor, @Current Shift, @Current Shift Start Time, @Employee type, @New Shift, @New Shift Start Time, @Days Off, @HR, @Shift Start, @Comments)"

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, myConn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Requestor", FName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee ID", LName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NT", NT)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACD", ACD)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", Account)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supervisor", Supervisor)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Current Shift", Shift)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Current Shift Start Time", Clocka)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee type", Emp)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@New Shift", Shiftnew)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@New Shift Start Time", Clock)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days Off", doff)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HR", HR)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift Start", Days)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", Commm)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConn.Close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your INSERT parameters don't match the list of parameters, for example, you have @FName, however in your parameters list you don't have a @FName parameter defined:

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (Requestor, Employee ID, NT, ACD, Account, Supervisor, Current Shift, Current Shift Start Time, Employee type, New Shift, New Shift Start Time, Days Off, HR, Shift Start, Comments) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @NT, @ACD, @Account, @Supervisor, @Shift, @Clocka, @Emp, @Shiftnew, @Clock, @doff, @HR, @Days, @Commm)"
```

The cmd parameters need to match the insert parameter names.

Answer (score 1):

And you should enclose your field names containing spaces in []. So instead of

```
insert into ....... Current Shift, Current Shift Start Time, ....
```

you will Need

```
insert into ....... [Current Shift], [Current Shift Start Time]
```

and in your add parameters block:

```
...                           
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift", Shift)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clocka", Clocka)
'            Parameter Name: ^         ^ your variable name
...
```